# I have a concept issue with simulated annealing?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, simulated-annealing

Suppose you are an AI programmer for a project that uses simulated  annealing to solve a search problem. After testing the program several times, you notice  that the program run too slowly. How would you modify the way T changes over time?

Comment: Don't focus too much on just Temperature. Check how proposals are created, and see if you can improve that, and/or the objective function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing),

> Unfortunately, there are no choices of these parameters that will be good for all problems, and there is no general way to find the best choices for a given problem.

The temperature adjustments depend on the shape of the problem, so you might have to experiment a bit and see what works in your specific setting. The general idea is that it cools off slowly towards the end to allow fine adjustments, and to stop the results from varying too much (as it should with any luck already be close to a good solution).